# How to make operations within each columns value of a pd.Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, math, sum, division

I have a **pandas Dataframe**, and I want to write into a the column `'final_data['130 + 71444']'` the result after make for each value inside the cells the following math operation:

```
final = pd.read_csv(path, header=0, parse_dates=True, index_col="Tagname")
final_data = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

[image]

---

***Edited***: I tried:

```
final_data['130 + 71444'] = (final_data['130.c'] + final_data['7144.c'])/final_data['c']
```

But the following error is displayed:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
final_data['130 + 71444'] = (final_data['130.c'].astype(float) + final_data['7144.c'].astype(float))/final_data['c'].astype(float)
```

If not working code above because some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `erriors='coerce'` for convert these values to missing values:

```
final_data['130 + 71444'] = (pd.to_numeric(final_data['130.c'], errors='coerce') + pd.to_numeric(final_data['7144.c'], errors='coerce') )/pd.to_numeric(final_data['c'], errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. It is like you defined:
**EDIT**
First you have to change the dtype of the columns. I am using here float.

```
final_data['130.c'] = final_data['130.c'].astype('float32')
final_data['7144.c'] = final_data['7144.c'].astype('float32')
final_data['c'] = final_data[c'].astype('float32')


final_data['130 + 71444'] = (final_data['130.c'] + final_data['7144.c'])/final_data['c']
```

this is possible, because you have numpy array as column in your data frame. See also the docs of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) and [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) .

Comment: I already tried, but I get the following Error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`